# uncomment code block not working

Tags: pycharm

As described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/commenting-and-uncommenting-blocks-of-code.html), I can comment code like so:

```
Ctrl+/
```

Unfortunately:

```
Ctrl+Shift+/
```

does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: `Ctrl+/` again should uncomment. Is it not working? Which version/OS?

Comment: thanks windows. will try.

Comment: you are right. is this an error in docu. Fell free to compose answer,. otherwise I will delete silly question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm, `Ctrl+/` toggles comment/uncomment.

`Ctrl+Shift+/` toggles *block* comment/uncomment.